# How to improve this php method?

Tags: php

Version1

```
$aData = $this->get($memberA); // came from db
$bData = $this->get($memberB); // came from db
if(empty($aData)) {
    $aData['updateTime'] = '1970-01-01';
}
if(empty($bData)) {
    $bData['updateTime'] = '1970-01-01';
}
if ($aData['updateTime'] >= $bData['updateTime']) {
     // if both data time have same value will echo A
     echo "A" ; 
} else { 
    echo "B"; 
}
```

Version2

```
$aData = $this->get($memberA); // came from db
$bData =  $this->get($memberB); // came from db
$flagA = empty($aData)? false: true; 
$flagB = empty($bData)? false: true;
if ($flagA === false && $flagB === true) {
    echo "B"; 
} else if ($flagA === true && $flagB === false) {
    echo "A";
} else if ($flagA === false && $flagB === false) { 
    echo "";
} else { 
    if ($aData['updateTime'] >= $bData['updateTime']) {
        // if both data time have same value will echo A 
        echo "A" ; 
    } else { 
        echo "B"; 
    }  
}
```

This is a function to compare two different time array, and the value of time array is not allow null.

Version one is my origin code.
In addition, I set a flag to depend this, but I am not sure that is a better way or not.

Does anyone have good idea to make this code clean?

Comment: Improve this to do what?

Comment: to work probably, comparing strings will not compare dates properly!

Comment: @Zong delboy1978uk is correct you can't compare date strings due to the fact that it only looks at the first set of numbers (aka the day). You need to create date objects and compare those using the built-in methods of PHP.

Comment: @MickaelLeger I mean that idea to make it clear.

Comment: @delboy1978uk , @C Hunter 
ok, i see. I didn't new a date in here because this array var was a timestamp came from database. Should i new a DateTime() again?

Answer (score 1):

To compare dates, you need to create a `new DateTime('1970-01-01');`
Then the comparison will work properly.

You'll also need to check `if(isset($aData['updateTime']))`, and if it exists, convert the string to a date time also, like this:

```
$aData['updateTime'] = new DateTime($aData['updateTime']);
```

Same for `$bdata`

Answer (score 0):

This is your code for your `Version 2`and how you can make some modification to make it works :

```
$aData = $this->get($memberA);
$bData = $this->get($memberB); 

// You create two empty string for the date you want to compare
$aDatetime = "";
$bDatetime = "";    

// You check if both data are not empty and if updateTime is defined
if (!empty($aData) && isset($aData['updateTime'])) {
    $aDatetime = new DateTime($aData['updateTime']);
} else {
    $aDatetime = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
}
if (!empty($bData) && isset($bData['updateTime'])) {
    $bDatetime = new DateTime($bData['updateTime']);
} else {
    $bDatetime = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
}
```

What you did before :

- You echo 'A' if `$bData` is empty AND `$aData` is not empty
- You echo 'A' if `$aData['updateTime'] >= $bData['updateTime']`
- You echo 'B' if `$aData` is empty AND `$bData` is not empty
- You echo 'B' if `$aData['updateTime'] < $bData['updateTime']`
- You echo '' if both `$aData` AND `$bData` are empty

You can do it with THREE condition now :

```
// Echo A if $aData['updateTime'] >= $bData['updateTime'] as before
// If $bData is empty, now it's a datetime for date 1970-01-01 so still true
// Add condition to check if $aDatetime is not '1970-01-01' to avoid case both data are empty
if ($aDatetime >= $bDatetime && $aDatetime->format('Y-m-d') !== '1970-01-01') {
    echo "A" ; 
// Echo B if $aData['updateTime'] < $bData['updateTime'] as before
// If $aData is empty, now it's a datetime for date 1970-01-01 so still true
} else if ($aDatetime < $bDatetime) {
    echo "B"; 
// This is the case where $aDatetime == $bDatetime and both are '1970-01-01' so both empty
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Output with date test :

- `$aData = '2018-10-23' && $bData = '2018-10-23'` : echo A
- `$aData = '2018-10-23' && $bData = '2018-10-20'` : echo A
- `$aData = '2018-10-20' && $bData = ''` : echo A
- `$aData = '2018-10-20' && $bData = '2018-10-23'` : echo B
- `$aData = '' && $bData = '2018-10-20'` : echo B
- `$aData = '' && $bData = ''` : echo ''